# Do I need to implement inherited methods in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, getter

I'm a beginner when it comes to Java and I have two questions that really concern me...

1. Isn't @Override kind of a code duplication? I mean, let me consider a situation.
   I implement a function in the Parent class. Then I create a Child class that inherits this method from the Parent class. Now I am able to use this function without implementing it once again in the Child class - it works. But is it a good practice? Or maybe I should write @Override and implement this function once again?
2. Do I need to @Override setters and getters from the Parent class? (And implement them in Child - just like in the previous question). Or maybe they should be abstract in Parent class?
   Thanks in advance :)

```java
class Animal { /*Parent class*/
    private int numOfLegs;
    protected String sound;

    public Animal(int numOfLegs, String sound) {
        this.numOfLegs = numOfLegs;
        this.sound = sound;
    }

    public int getNumOfLegs() {
        return numOfLegs;
    }

    public void makeSound() {
        System.out.println(sound);
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal{ /*Child class*/
    public Dog(int numOfLegs, String sound) {
        super(numOfLegs, sound);
    }

    @Override /*Is it necessery to implement an inherited function?*/
    public void makeSound() {
        System.out.println(sound);
    }

    /*Do I need to implement an inherited getter?/*

}
```

Comment: You only need to override methods when you want to **change** the inherited function! So the answer to both of your questions is **no**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of overriding, as the name suggests, is to override/replace/change the behaviour of the parent method. There is no point in overriding a method with the same implementation. You can just use the inherited method if you don't want to change anything.

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't @Override kind of a code duplication?

If you duplicate the same code (as in the parent) you lose the point for what override is intended: Define a new code for a method you parent has already defined.

For the contrary, it's about code re-use: we re-use what it is useful for use (the methods that we don't override and don't want to repeat in a whole separate new class) and we only override which needs to be changed.

> ...is it a good practice?

It is not a matter of a good practice to override a code but a matter of modify the behavior of a method inherited from a parent class (there are lots of reasons for why we do this)

> Or maybe I should write @Override and implement this function once
>   again?

Again, you only override the method if you need to.

Now, what it is a **good practice** is when you override a method you SHOULD annotate it with **`@Override`** (if you don't do it, it works too, but you will lose the useful info the compiler can give with this annotation: for example check that you're actually overriding the method and not creating an overload because of the method signature is different from the one in the parent)

> Do I need to @Override setters and getters from the Parent class?

Sometimes, only if the use case requires it, but it is not common to see this.

> Or maybe they should be abstract in Parent class?

About they being abstract, well, that is a completely different (but closely related, I know) topic.

They should be abstract only if in the parent class there is not enough information to implement those methods, information that depends on the concrete implementation (in the children classes).

**Example use case**:

Most of the birds fly, right, some other don't: If we create a class `Bird` we can have a method `getMovement` which returns "Fly". Now if we create a class `Penguin` we **need** to override that, because they don't fly. Also in the `Bird` class there is a method `getCover` which returns "Feathers", in the class `Penguin` we don't need to override it, because they have feathers too :)

```
public class Bird {

    // for most birds this is OK, they fly
    public String getMovement() {
        return "Fly";
    }

    public String getCover() {
        return "Feathers";
    }

}

public class Penguin extends Bird {

    // penguins don't fly, so we need to override the parent method in order to create more realistic penguins
    @Override
    public String getMovement() {
        return "Walk";
    }
    //we don't override getCover because penguins do have "Feather"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must override your method from parent class only of you want to override super class. But you must override every methodsfrom Iterface when you implement it by some of your class.

So, you can you use from some method in Dog class like super.makeSound() or Just makeSound() if you don't want to override it in Child class, for example do not make sound but make jump or something else.